# How to match whitespace, carriage return and line feed using regular expression in PHP?

Tags: php, html, regex, whitespace, carriage-return

I am working with a regular expression in PHP. I have the following string:

```
<img 
src="/files/admin/hotel_website.gif" alt="Go To The Hotel's Web 
Site" align="absmiddle" border="0" class="hotel_icon" />
```

This string contains carriage return and line feed characters.

I want my regular expression to replace html img tags with IMG but this does not work with the above text.

I discovered it contained these characters by looping through each character in the string and printing out the hexadecimal representation which can be found here (http://pastebin.com/ViNdBsRV).

Here is my regular expression:

```
strip_tags(preg_replace('/^\s*<img\s*.*\/?>\s*$/i', '[IMG]', $test));
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you please show me string do you expect from the start string ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This:

```
preg_replace("#<img.+?/>#is", '[IMG]', $test)
```

Personally when I'm making a regular expression I always try to go the shortest/simplest.
Here you want to replace an entire tag, which starts with '`<img`' and ends with '`/>`', '`.+?`' is a non greedy (lazy) catch.
And for the modifiers '`i`' for the case and '`s`' to `.` the possibility to be a new lines.

More on greedyness vs lazyness : http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html
More on modifiers: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: This works as expected, thanks for the comprehensive explanation. I tweaked it slightly to fit other cases too: /<img.+?\/?>\s*$/is

Comment: @Sid You don't need to add `\s$` my solution already works to replace `<img />` on a whole page (this is how I tested the regex).

Comment: I added $ because I'm getting the html string from a database table.

Answer (score 131):

To match new lines: `[\n\r]+` *(matches one or more new line characters)*

To match whitespace: `\s+` or `[\n\r\s]+` *(It matches one or more space characters and one or more new line characters. Both regexes are equal.)*

Comment: I added this to my regular expression but it does not work; '/^\s*<img[\s\r\n]*.*\/?>\s*$/i'

Comment: Don't forget that you have to use an interpreted string with quotation marks for this to be effective!  ' will just result in the literal.

Comment: What should be the expression if I only want CRLF space?

Comment: @SankalpKotewar I feel like you need the same. I didn't test it, but the `\n` stands for `LF` while the `\r` stands for `CR`, _(At least I hope I am not wrong.)_. Did you try it with just the `[\n\r]`?

Comment: `\s` implicitly matches `\r` and `\n` too, so `[\n\r\s]` is superfluous and just equivalent to `\s`.

Comment: This highly upvoted answer is giving bad advice.  `\s` (as previously commented) is all that is required.  I wonder how many developers have this suboptimal pattern in their projects.

Comment: @mickmackusa The answer was wrong wording. It solved the asked problem. I just updated to make it more clear. Hope this makes you more happy :)

Comment: The bad advice is: `[\n\r\s]` -- that should be reduced to `\s` because `\r` and `\n` are found within `\s`.  This is what Marcel's comment was trying to tell you.

Comment: @mickmackusa you are right. I fixed once more the answer, Thank you for contributing.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me it matches multiple spaces and multilines, also any other character or symbol.

```
[\S+\n\r\s]+
```

Hope this helps anyone.

It matches for example:

```
stpd  : asdfasdf
this is also matching ***
```

Comment: Puttting a `+` inside `[]` makes it match a literal plus. `\S` is opposite of `\s`, so you're basically matching any character. `[\s\S]+` is the solution as `.` does not *normally* match newline characters. There's not much use for this match itself.